# Interactive Maps in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting-services-map

**Interactive Maps in SSRS**

How can I create an interactive map in SSRS?
I know that I can do it with a spatial data (but I haven't the spatial data) or use an SHP file to create it. Finally I found a solution on how to create a map but I'm not able to add a data field to some specific province or country.

Does anyone know how work with that type of task?

Answer (score 2):

1. Hi I found this URL may be is useful for someone looking for the same problem :)
   http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event9/Fast_Track_to_Spatial_Reporting